# Can't establish Appium session between PCs

Tags: java, xcode, appium

My Setup: prod station(Windows 7) and Virtual Box(Mojave 10), Appium Server - 1.13.0, Clients: IntelliJ - 2019.1, iOS Simulator - SE 12.1
In my setup one Appium Server(local) calling another Server(virtual box).

IntelliJ's call stack:

```
May 21, 2019 10:45:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at lib.ui.MainPageObject.waitWithId(MainPageObject.java:28)
    at lib.ui.WelcomePageObject.waitForLearnMoreWikipedia(WelcomePageObject.java:20)
    at tests.iOS.getStartedTest.testPassThroughWelcome(getStartedTest.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Mojave's Appium Server call stack:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Appium server calling another virtual server?

Comment: I have bridged interface between stations